# Exibir função get_user_role e get_author_role em português

Tags: php, wordpress, funções

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Wordpress que utiliza a função *get_author_role*, no entanto não estou conseguindo fazer com que ela apareça em Português.

A primeira função modifica os nomes padrões:

```
function change_role_name() {
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    // Administrador - tem acesso a virtualmente todas as funções de administração.
    $wp_roles->roles['administrator']['name'] = 'Administrador';
    $wp_roles->role_names['administrator'] = 'Administrador';

    // Editor - pode publicar e gerenciar posts e páginas, além de gerenciar posts de outros usuários.
    $wp_roles->roles['editor']['name'] = 'Moderador';
    $wp_roles->role_names['editor'] = 'Moderador';

    // Autor - só pode publicar e gerenciar seus próprios posts.
    $wp_roles->roles['author']['name'] = 'Suporte';
    $wp_roles->role_names['author'] = 'Suporte';

    // Colaborador - pode escrever e gerenciar suas posts, mas não publicá-los: são enviados para revisão de além com função superior.
    $wp_roles->roles['contributor']['name'] = 'Estagiário';
    $wp_roles->role_names['contributor'] = 'Estagiário';

    // Assinante - só pode gerenciar o próprio perfil, mas não escrever posts. Útil para marcação de favoritos, gerenciamento de comentários, etc.
    $wp_roles->roles['subscriber']['name'] = 'Membro';
    $wp_roles->role_names['subscriber'] = 'Membro';
}

add_action('init', 'change_role_name');
```

A segunda mostra qual e o nível do do autor do post:

```
function get_author_role() {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489214/getting-an-authors-role-in-wordpress
    global $authordata;
    $author_roles = $authordata->roles;
    $author_role = array_shift($author_roles);
    return $author_role;
}
```

Eu chamo a função com o código abaixo:

```
<?php echo get_author_role(); ?>
```

O problema começa quando e para exibir a função *get_author_role*, em vez de aparecer escrito *Administrador*, aparece escrito *administrator*.

Já tentei todo método disponível na internet, tentei o *translate_user_role* no entanto não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de 8 dias procurando uma solução, consegui resolver com olhando no site do wordpress.

Link da solução: [Por Vladimir Garagulia (@shinephp)](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-author-role-in-author-box/#post-9920441)

Assumindo que $authordata contém uma matriz de funções de usuário de autor válida

```
function get_author_role_name()
{
    global $authordata;

    $author_roles = $authordata->roles;
    $role = array_shift($author_roles);
    $wp_roles = wp_roles();
    // take role display name by role ID
    $role_name = $wp_roles->role_names[$role];

    return $role_name;
}
```

Use esta função, em seguida, onde você deseja dar saída ao nome de exibição da função de autor.